# Use am/pm to create php timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a couple textboxes that allows a person to enter a time and date. The time is entered with a textbox for hours, a textbox for minutes, a drop down for am/pm and some drop downs for months/hours/years

So, I'd like to combine all of these to create a timestamp out of it and save it to the database.

But i've confused myself in how to do all that to create a proper timestamp, especially with the AM/PM part.

Comment: What kind of timestamp? UNIX time, MySQL timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you'd just use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). Get the correct hour number by adding 12 for pm, then pass the arguments into the function.

```
if($is_pm) $hour += 12;
$time = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
```

If you're looking for a MySQL timestamp instead of a UNIX timestamp, you have two options:

1. Build the timestamp in MySQL's format using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);`
2. Let MySQL do it for you: `UPDATE table SET date = FROM_UNIXTIME($time) WHERE foo='bar'`

Or you could just store the integer timestamp in the database as an integer.

Comment: oh my that's ridiculously easy. How i didn't even consider that is pretty silly. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

[strtotime][1] will do this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day $hours:$minutes $am_pm");
```

Just make sure to zero-pad $month, $day, $hours, and $minutes.
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I'd expect mktime would have better performance than parsing a string, however.

Comment: You're probably right, but I traded off a slight performance hit for simpler handling of AM/PM.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've already checked for valid input, you can use the [mktime()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function. If PM is selected, just add 12 to the hours. That will give you back a Unix Timestamp. You can pass that result to [date()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format the date however you would like.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following to convert it to a unix timestamp:

```
strtotime("2009/01/02 12:13:14 PM");
strtotime("2009/01/02 12:13:14 AM");
```

PHP Manual reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php